# How to deselect text in QTextBrowser

Tags: python, pyqt, qtextbrowser

The code below creates a single `QTextBrowser`, fills it with 25 lines of text and finds a line 'Line of text # 0011' using `view.find` method which aside from finding the text selects it as well.

How to deselect the text selected by `.find` method?

[image]

```
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui
app = QtGui.QApplication([])

view = QtGui.QTextBrowser() 
for i in range(25):
    view.append('Line of text # %004d'%i )

view.moveCursor(QtGui.QTextCursor.End)
view.find('Line of text # 0011', QtGui.QTextDocument.FindBackward)

view.show()
app.exec_()
```

Comment: It was not a duplication! The QTextBrowser is not equal with the QTextEdit wich is linked to this question.